# the meaning of : and @ in svn propget svn:mergeinfo output

Tags: svn, merge

I'm trying to figure out the exact revisions of source branches that were merged into a destination branch in svn 1.7, and I thought this would do it:

```
svn propget svn:mergeinfo ^/branches/mydestination
```

I expected the source revisions to appear after the : but I see there is also an @ symbol which sometimes appears on either side of what seem to be revision numbers.  And sometimes both symbols are there:

```
^/branches/mysource-a:6,8,12@
^/branches/mysource-b@15
^/branches/mysource-c@17,20-21
```

So my question is, what exactly do the : and @ symbols denote, and where should I look to find the revision number(s) of the source branches that were merged into the destination branch?